# What could make a commit not appear in git log for a given file?

Tags: git

I have encounted a weird behavior, and would like to understand what is happening.

The commit I'm interested in has hash 4679774add0540e3e8f62937ed16855694a3f465 and appears on my dev branch when looking at the history of my-file.htm

```
$git log origin/dev my-file.htm | grep 4679774add0540e3e8f62937ed16855694a3f465
commit 4679774add0540e3e8f62937ed16855694a3f465
```

The only modification in the commit is on the file I'm interested in:

```
$git log --name-status -1 --pretty='' 4679774add0540e3e8f62937ed16855694a3f465
M       my-file.htm
```

Now, I also have that commit on my feat branch :

```
$git log origin/feat | grep 4679774add0540e3e8f62937ed16855694a3f465
commit 4679774add0540e3e8f62937ed16855694a3f465
```

The weird thing is that the commit won't appear when looking at the history for the file on the feat branch:

```
$git log origin/feat my-file.htm | grep 4679774add0540e3e8f62937ed16855694a3f465
< Nothing >
```

What am I missing here?

Update: the --follow option has allowed me to find back my commit

```
$git log -6 origin/feat --raw --oneline --follow -- my-file.htm
38f0c748ab
:100644 100644 e1ab553d85 40ec4c0996 M  my-file.htm

9fc49fff8b
:100644 100644 14911a3459 e1ab553d85 M  my-file.htm

4679774add <=== HERE IT IS!
:100644 100644 f9c83e9a19 40ec4c0996 M  my-file.htm

a9ed386008
:100644 100644 41721ec5ce f9c83e9a19 M  my-file.htm

f5256795c9
:100644 100644 14911a3459 41721ec5ce M  my-file.htm

a859b07f2d
:100644 100644 e5c188935d 14911a3459 M  my-file.htm
```

The question is now to understand why there is a break in the tracking for the file, where there have only been modifications to the content, and not the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `--full-history`. `git log` normally does [history simplification](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification), where when tracing back it tries to ignore things you're not looking for.

Git's usual interpretation of a specified path is "show me commits that explain the current state of the file", so if for instance the commit you know about is on a side branch and that change was reverted during the merge, when Git's looking at that merge it'll see the side branch contributed nothing to the file's current state and not bother walking through it -- whatever's in there got reverted so it didn't affect your current checkout, it's not the source of whatever change you're looking for.

There may be other ways to produce what you're seeing, but this would do it, it's an heuristic that when it has any effect at all generally does exactly what people want, hiding redundant commits (so if a commit was cherrypicked it won't show all of them).

You can also add `-m` to see if the change really was reverted during a merge, `git log` also generally doesn't check those because it assumes you're looking for the commits that caused changes not the ones just carrying them forward.

Comment: Ooooh, I learned something today. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Seems your file has no changes. You can check which files were changed in your commit:

```
git log --name-status -1 --pretty='' 4679774add0540e3e8f62937ed16855694a3f465
```

Comment: It is the only file modified by that commit :/

     $git log --name-status -1 --pretty='' 4679774add0540e3e8f62937ed16855694a3f465
     M       practice-home.htm

Comment: @RomainPrévost is that the file you're looking for?

Comment: Ho yes, sorry, I renamed it in the original question, but it is the one.

Comment: @RomainPrévost tried to recreate your case, no luck... what git version?

Comment: The commits were not mine. I have looked into it with 2.40.0.windows.1 and 2.25.1 on WSL. They have probably been made with Visual Studio (regular, not VS Code).
When I look from Github, I find the commit in the feat branch, I see the mod in the file, but when I look a the file history for the feat branch, the commit is not there.
When I look at the dev branch, the commit is there, and I can also see the commit in the file history.

Comment: I'm not allowed to for work, sorry. But I have edited my question with new information.